# How to have Gradle task depend on another task but not re-execute if the other executes?

Tags: gradle

I would like to have one Gradle task, `taskA`, to trigger the execution of another task, `taskB`, if both aren't up-to-date but the execution of `taskB` shouldn't trigger an execution of `taskA` if only `taskB` isn't up-to-date. How can this be done?

IOW, there are two parts of the task dependency involved here, the task hierarchy and the up-to-date checks. I would like to bed able to set up the task hierarchy but not have it imply the up-to-date check for `taskA`.

Context: `taskA` must execute if its inputs change or if `taskB` executes on a dev machine (ie not CI). `taskB` must execute if it's not up-to-date. This is because the output of `taskB` is an executable that's run by `taskA`. The reason `taskA` shouldn't run if only the executable is updated is because the updated executable can produce different output than the previous executable. That new output can cause issues with other parts of the build. Since the purpose of the output is to help ensure users are following best practices, the new output of the updated executable can be ignored in CI builds.

More concretely, `taskA` calls a [`protolock`](https://github.com/nilslice/protolock) binary which is output by `taskB`. `taskA` outputs a `proto.lock` file which engineers should commit. Auto-committing that file can lead to surprises for engineers and to subversion of the purpose of these checks.

Comment: Well, at what point does `taskA.dependsOn taskB` not meet your requirements?

Comment: Indeed, if your only task dependency was `taskA.dependsOn taskB`, then `taskA` wouldn’t be executed if you ran `gradle taskB`. If it still does, then there must be more in your build configuration than you have told us.

Comment: Yes, there are other dependencies involved. I'm not seeing why that would matter in this question.

Comment: Lukas, that `dependOn` would trigger the execution of `taskA` if `taskB` were executed. I don't want that to happen.

Comment: I've made the question more precise.

Comment: I'm *relatively* sure that `taskA.dependsOn taskB` will *not* execute `taskA` if you invoke `./gradlew taskB`.

Comment: `build` will call `taskA`. If `gradlew build` is called, `taskB` should be executed if it's not up-to-date. `taskA` should only be executed if its direct inputs (ie the `.proto` files) aren't up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

Use `onlyIf`:

```
taskB.onlyIf {
  trueIffNotCiOrInputsAreNewerThanOutput()
}
```